# SQL Server update query update two table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server. I have written an update statement using a join. I try to update one column in the table, but my update statement removes the value from another table. I do not understand why it is happening even though I am updating value for one column.

```
update rs
set rs.col1 = t.col2
from table1 r
join table2 rs on rs.Id = r.Id
join @temp t on t.Id = rs.Id
```

I am trying to update `col1` value in `table2` but it updates the value both in `table2` for `col1` and in `table1`

Comment: An `update` statement in SQL Server only updates one table.  You are misunderstanding something, unless you have a trigger on `table2`.

Comment: Do you have triggers on those tables?

Comment: I do not have trigger on those tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your joins. I've also just renamed some of the Aliases of the tables to make the statement a bit more clearer.

```
update t2
set t2.col1 = t.col2
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    join @temp t on t.Id= t2.Id
```

Comment: is there a technical problem with my join or is it a naming problem?

Comment: Just looking at it again, don't think there is a technical issue. I would have a look at user Pawek Tajs question to see if there is anything else that might be interfering with the data.

Comment: Could it be possible that all this is happening because there is relationship in between these two tables?

Comment: Pretty sure it should be ok. Certainly the statement looks correct and only one column should be updated. If you convert the above to just a SELECT statement to output the values in t2.col1 and t.col1, does it all look ok ?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: `SELECT t.col2, t2.id, t1.id, t.id
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    join @temp t on t.Id= t2.Id` All 3 id columns should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Cascade rules must available there on tables. On Update cascade delete cascade rule available on tables.

When you are updating column of one table by Cascade rule it is deleting value from another table. Check whether you have applied Cascade rule on table or not.
If Cascade rule is applicable on both tables table1 and table2 then first remove that cascade rule and again try to update it.

Comment: I checked it. There are no cascading rule applied on the tables.